# Nested map iterator in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm have Nested Map output in my code like below

```
Map(test -> 113123, "cat" -> None, myList -> Map(test2 -> 321323, test3 -> 11122))
```

But I wanted output like below using scala iterator if anyone knows please help me on this as I'm very new Scala

```
Map(test -> 113123, "cat" -> None, myList -> Some(Map(test2 -> 321323, test3 -> 11122)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that you have data like

```
val data = Map("test" -> 113123, "cat" -> None, "myList" -> Map("test2" -> 321323, "test3" -> 11122))
//data: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(test -> 113123, cat -> None, myList -> Map(test2 -> 321323, test3 -> 11122))
```

Then you can do

```
val output = data.map(x => if (x._2.isInstanceOf[Map[String, Long]]) (x._1 -> Some(x._2)) else x)
//output: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(test -> 113123, cat -> None, myList -> Some(Map(test2 -> 321323, test3 -> 11122)))
```

to get your desired output

And you can use `println` to see the `output` as

```
println(output)
//Map(test -> 113123, cat -> None, myList -> Some(Map(test2 -> 321323, test3 -> 11122)))
```

Comment: val output = data.map(x => if (x._2.isInstanceOf[Map[String, Long]]) (x._1 -> Some(x._2)) else x)  println(output), i'm not getting any output for this, could you please help me on this

Comment: you have to print them or save it in a file.

Comment: I want to create the new map from existing map with some value

Comment: I wanted output like this : Map(test -> 113123, "cat" -> None, myList -> Some(Map(test2 -> 321323, test3 -> 11122)))

Comment: myMap.mapValues {
  case v@Option => v
  case v => Some(v)
}

Comment: @JSFLearner I have updated with the output . you get use scala REPL to see the immediate output

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, In REPL it's working but when using it in scala class not printing any value.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, please help me if you can

Comment: you will have to tell me how you are doing in scala and in REPL